# ASP Button Event not firing into UserControl UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a page with an `UpdatePanel` that calls a `UserControl` with another `UpdatePanel`. The `LinkButton` event into the user control `UpdatePanel` is not firing.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPost" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="linkComment" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkComment" runat="server"
             OnClick="linkComment_Click" OnClientClick="return showCommentBox()"
             CssClass="PostComment" Text="Comment" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This code is into a usercontrol called in other page update panel.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Yeah. It's really hard to understand what you are asking. Please provide a concrete example or code snippets.

Comment: sorry, i already added. this is my first post. Do you understand my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please show your markup so we can see how your triggers are defined, you should have at least one trigger, something like so:

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MyButton" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPost" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="linkComment" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="linkComment" runat="server" **OnClick="linkComment_Click"**             OnClientClick="return showCommentBox()" CssClass="PostComment" Text="Comment" />
 </ContentTemplate>
    
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: what is this return showCommentBox() returning...if it is always returning false, the link event wont ever fire. so check the return value of this showCommentBox()

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up the simple stuff, have you included the ScriptManager tag on your page?

i.e. `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />`